# What signals should I catch for clipboard pasting and character insertion in GTK?

Tags: python, gtk, clipboard, pygtk, signals

I have a Window with a TextView, and I would like to perform some actions when the user pastes some text.

I would also like to know what signal(s) should I catch in order to perform something when the user presses a key inside the TextView.

Can you tell me what are the signals I must connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For paste: Take a look at the [paste-done](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#GtkTextBuffer-paste-done) signal of the `GtkTextBuffer` class, it sounds about right.

For regular character insert: [insert-text](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#GtkTextBuffer-insert-text).